# CSS footer overlapping my content

Tags: html, css

Hello I've made a fixed footer and its still overlapping my content even if my wrapper is set to padding: 100px;

HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="copyright">
        <p>Copyright (c) 2016-2017 <?=$lang["website-title"];?> | All rights reserved.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#footer {width: 100%; height: auto; bottom: 0px; position: fixed;}
#footer .copyright {height: 30px; background: #171C21; line-height: 30px;}
#footer .copyright > p {color: #fff; text-align: center; font-size: 13px;}
```

Prev: https://awesomeness.adam.zur.io/

Comment: create, please, jsfiddle with your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
#wrapper .left-box .content > article {
   padding: 10px 10px 100px 10px;
   color: #fff;
}
```

Your `padding-bottom:100px` needs to be in the article container itself. There are other issues in your site that result to this, but that's another problem :)

**FREEBIE**

Fix the z-order in your header with this:

```
h3:first-of-type {
   z-index: 1;
}
```